# Объединить ячейки при display:table

Tags: css

Есть таблица, сверстанная по принципу `<div>`, которые `display:table;` ну и вопрос, как объединить столбцы и ячейки? 
Выглядеть должно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.
P.s. интересует объединение СТОИМОСТИ и того, что под ней.

Comment: Keep it simple.
Если нужна таблица, то не нужно юзать `div` или ещё как изворачиваться. Делай таблицу через `table`.

Comment: <table> очень некорректно отображается в Opera, к тому же, это будет означать, что нужно переделывать еще одну таблицу на более, чем 50 позиций, + разве табличная верстка не устарела?

Comment: Некорректно? Ну не знаю, вроде нормально.
Лучше переделать, чем мучиться с тем, что для этого не предназначено. Обычно формирование происходит в цикле, а значит поменять нужно одну строчку - та, которая в цикле. Предположение это.
Она не устарела, просто раньше каждый первый делал сайт в виде большой таблицы, что, конечно, было использованием её не по назначению. Сейчас появились новые, улучшенные средства делать то, что таблица НЕ ДОЛЖНА делать. Поэтому сформировалось такое отношение к таблицам, но это чушь - используй по назначению и be happy!

Comment: @AnnaFrank верстать таблицы с помощью специально созданных для этого табличных элементов разметки - это норма и семантически правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как вариант, но все таки `table` вполне справляется с табличными данными (хотя это личное дело что и как использовать)

Также в какой версии Оперы не корректно отображаются таблицы?

http://jsfiddle.net/3yc12hgu/

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.table{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;    
    background: #ccc;
}
.table-item{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;    
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.table-item-row{
    display: table-row;    
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-item"></div>
    <div class="table-item">
        <div class="table">
             <div class="table-item-row"></div>
            <div class="table-item-row">
                <div class="table-item"></div>
                <div class="table-item"></div>
                <div class="table-item"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-item"></div>
    <div class="table-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ох, спасибо. Подумаем.